Hong Mandel Effect - question on math of indistinguishability of photons
I’m working on the transformations of multi-photon states through a beam splitter, and I encountered confusion in some normalization factors . Using beam splitter transformations:
$$ \hat{a}^\dagger \to t \hat{a}^\dagger - r \hat{b}^\dagger \qquad 
 \hat{b}^\dagger \to t \hat{b}^\dagger + r \hat{a}^\dagger $$
I tried to write down the equation for transformation of state $|1,1\rangle$ in a two photon two input beam-splitter setup like in Hong-mandel effect.
$$ |1, 1\rangle \to (t \hat{a}^\dagger - r \hat{b}^\dagger)(t \hat{b}^\dagger + r \hat{a}^\dagger) = 
t^2 \hat{a}^\dagger \hat{b}^\dagger - r^2 \hat{a}^\dagger \hat{b}^\dagger + t r \hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a}^\dagger - r t \hat{b}^\dagger \hat{b}^\dagger
$$
My question is why normalization is NOT done here? Because the resultant of this has $(t^2-r^2) |11\rangle$ instead of $\frac{(t^2-r^2)}{\sqrt(t^4+r^4)}|11\rangle$ ?
From what I understand that is the way to normalize due to the indistinguishability of photons - We find the total probability of the states which "were distinguishable" and divide by the square root of that. Thats what I think is done in the case of transformation of $|20\rangle$, the reason for having the $\sqrt2$ term:
$$ |2, 0\rangle \to (t \hat{a}^\dagger - r \hat{b}^\dagger)^2 = t^2 |2, 0\rangle - \sqrt{2}tr |1, 1\rangle + r^2 |0, 2\rangle 
$$
So please point out where am I going wrong in my reasoning, and if possible, add a resource for me to study the correct method of doing this (already tried searching internet without luck). Thanks!
Cross-post link: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/823293/hong-mandel-effect-question-on-math-of-indistinguishability-of-photons

In case you aren't able to get answers here, you can try the physics stackexchange https://physics.stackexchange.com/

If it is not normalized, it is because you made a mistake.

@NorbertSchuch it is a simple calculation which i believe is correct, and is very easy to verify. If you see an error, can you please point it out?

Please cross-link your crossposts! Otherwise you cause double work to people, which is rather incosiderate!

Your state is perfectly normalized if you use that $(a^\dagger)^2|0\rangle = \sqrt{2}|2\rangle$ (where $|0\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ are normalized states): Its norm is
$$
(t^2-r^2)^2 + (\sqrt{2}tr)^2 + (\sqrt{2}tr)^2  
= (t^2+r^2)^2 =1 \ .
$$
